# App crashes when passing data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass some data from fragmentA through an activity to start an action in fragmentB.
The way it should work is, user presses an item i a listview(listFragment), items data gets send to another fragment (which is visible and running already) to start a new event/action using the data from fragmentA.

FragmentA:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long longId) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, longId);

    String trackId = SD_PATH + songs.get(position);
    mCallbacks.onTrackSelected(trackId);
```

Through activity:

```
@Override
public void onTrackSelected(String trackId) {

            // This starts onTrackSelected() method in fragmentB
    topBarFragment topBarFragment = (topBarFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topBar_fragment);
    topBarFragment.onTrackSelected();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("trackId", trackId);
      //set Fragmentclass Arguments
    topBarFragment fragObject = new topBarFragment();
    fragObject.setArguments(bundle);

}
```

retrieve data in fragmentB (this is where is crashes):

```
public void onTrackSelected() {

    // crashes on this line
    String trackId = getArguments().getString("trackId");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), trackId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I've checked and the data gets passes fine from `fragmentA` to `activity`, but then it crashes when trying to receive it `fragmentB`.

What to do?

(fragmentB's parrent activity is not the same as fragmentA's. Can this have something to do with it?)

logcat:

```
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at com.harteg.fragmentstest.topBarFragment.onTrackSelected(topBarFragment.java:47)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at com.harteg.fragmentstest.ItemListActivity.onTrackSelected(ItemListActivity.java:83)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at com.harteg.fragmentstest.TracksFragment.onListItemClick(TracksFragment.java:136)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 23:28:47.757: E/AndroidRuntime(14047):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE:**

I updated my code like this, and found out that getArguments() returns null.. Why is that?

```
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null)
    {
        String trackId = getArguments().getString("trackId");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), trackId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "arguments returns null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I updated the onTrackSelected() in the activity like this, but now it crashes and says that fragment is already active. How do you fix this?

```
@Override
public void onTrackSelected(String trackId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        topBarFragment topBarFragment = (topBarFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topBar_fragment);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("trackId", trackId);
          //set Fragmentclass Arguments
//      topBarFragment fragObject = new topBarFragment();
        topBarFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        topBarFragment.onTrackSelected();

    }
```

Comment: Which line is **47** ?

Comment: @MarekSebera line 47 is: String trackId = getArguments().getString("trackId");

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting arguments for the first TopBarFragment? It seems that getArguments() is returning null.

Comment: @VictorKP what do you mean with: the first topBarFragment ?

Comment: Nevermind, that was poorly worded. It would help if you just add some debug statements to determine what is null. Check getArguments() in TopBarFragment and getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topBar_fragment).

Comment: @VictorKP I found out with an if statement that getArguments() returns null, as you said. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity's `onTrackSelected()` method you use `topBarFragment` twice. The first one probably from your layout file (or from a previous transaction). Anyway, this first fragment doesn't have the arguments yet, but you call `onTrackSelected()` anyway. You should put the call at the very end.

And check why you created it anew at the end of the method as well (not related to this problem, but probably unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks, I think this might have been the problem, and I updated my onTrackSelected() method, but now it crashes and says that the fragment is already active. (I updated the question with modified code) thank you

Comment: Yes. You are not allowed to call this method on an active instance. If you want to keep the same instance around - and why not - you should use a custom method of your fragment. Or simply pass the value into the `onTrackSelected()` method of your fragment.